# The Answer is in the Question…

Tags: riddle

So I have a question for you all, it's probably not too hard for you but it's relatively simple:

**How many times does *variable* appear?**

The hint for the variable is pretty short too:

*I am very small, you think of me little, you can find me in many places, even though I'm tiny. I am even in here.*

I'll accept the answer with an explanation, and a spoiler.

Comment: An interesting title. Any puzzle having a definite solution necessarily contains some reasonable encoding of its own answer, for reasonable definitions of "reasonable". It certainly applies here.

Comment: This question makes me nervous because editors need to be careful not to change the answer. On the other hand, once you have the answer to the italicized riddle, the answer to the bolded question is simple. With that in mind, I think "variable" is a strange word to use... I would have said something like "the answer". The problem is, even if that's deemed a better word, it would be bad to edit the question!

Comment: You can change it to "do I". This corresponds to the hint.

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop You see the thing with that is, any edits have to be approved by me or someone higher up. I'm not going to edit it, and if I approve one I'll make sure the answer is the same. If it's someone like DoorKnob whom I don't have to approve, I'm sure they'd be careful enough.

Comment: @warspyking admittedly, I'm not nervous because I'm worried that someone will accidentally mess up the question; I'm worried that the question was designed in such a way as to resist editing. I do love "meta" style questions, but this one is hurting the SE format!

Comment: What do you mean "designed in such a way as to resist editing" and how does it hurt the SE format?

Comment: I belive @EnvisionAndDevelop means that the wording is very specific, and needs to be for the riddle to work. However, I believe "How many times do I appear" is a valid question with the same answer - it can't be taken as "the letter I" because that would be "How many times does I appear?", and it's obvious that the idea to find out what the "I" refers to

Comment: Just placing the word variable doesn't make it 'a' variable. So the wording is (imo) off, which comes close to this: [https://xkcd.com/169/]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer:

> 29, or 33 including the title of the question

Explanation:

> The first question is what "variable" refers to. The hint says that it is in "here". To me this indicates that it should be a letter, and since "you can find [it] in many places", I believe it is the most common of the letters in the word "here" - 'e'. Then I counted the number of 'e's in the entire question.

Comment: Even better, the hint says it is *even* in 'here', and only one letter shows up an even amount of times in 'here' (discounting zero times for most letters).

Comment: @Geobits: Not only does it show up an even number of times, but it shows up in the even positions: 2, and 4. (Assuming 1-based indexing).

Answer (score 7):

Question:

**How many times does *variable* appear?**

Answer: (is in the question)

> Twice.

Explanation:

> The word *variable* appears in the question once, and also once in the extraneous data.

Answer (score 5):

> My first bet was a period `.`, the smallest visible character in the question. Found three times in the question body and three more times in the title.

Comment: Are you British? From what I know, "." is a period.

Comment: You didn't have to change it, I was just wondering.

Comment: Oh and actually, a period do not appear 3 times in the title, that is a suspension point.

Comment: @warspyking That's known as an ellipsis.

Answer (score 4):

Objection!

> Why is the letter e considered as tiny? If we're talking about written language components, the dot would be more appropriate in my opinion. "It's in here" can imply that the variable is present in the question block, not just the word "here".

My two cents:

> The dot. It appears multiple times in the question: 3 times as a period, 3 times as an element of the character i.

Comment: It's tiny because it's lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

> The letter "e" appears 33 times including the number that are in the title.

Answer (score 1):

> Actually if you say variable as a "word" it has appeared one time, if you say variable as a "place holder" as programming languages, it has appeared 33 times (along with the question).